# Installing Oracle WebLogic Server 12.2.1.0.0 through Run the Quick Installer jar file in Windows 10

Tags: java, weblogic12c

I am trying to install Oracle WebLogic Server 12.2.1.0.0 for Java 8 through Run the Quick Installer jar file. This is what I've done:

But when I run the Quick Installer jar file `fmw_12.2.1.0.0_wls_quick`

I got this error:

```
C:\Users\xuriguera\Downloads\wls_12.2.1.0.0>java -jar fmw_12.2.1.0.0_wls_quick.jar
Launcher log file is C:\Users\xuriguera\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2018-11-06_09-10-15AM\launcher2018-11-06_09-10-15AM.log.
Extracting files.......
This installer must be executed using a Java Development Kit (JDK)
but C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_192 is not a valid JDK.
```

but when I check the sets on my machine, I got this:

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Pgm\Java\jdk1.8.0_191
Path=C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin;;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Pgm\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\bin;C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Enterprise Vault\EVClient\;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Pgm\apache-maven-3.5.4\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Pgm\Git\bin;C:\Users\xuriguera\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
```

no reference at all about **jre1.8.0_192**

I also set the JAVA_HOME manually before start with the same result

```
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Pgm\Java\jdk1.8.0_191
```

Comment: You need to replace the hard coded path (C:\Pgm\Java\jdk1.8.0_191) to "%JAVA_HOME%\bin"  in PATH environment variable.

Comment: and before you install Weblogic using the .jar file, check the version of the JAVA. Use command "java -version"

Comment: And if version is "1.8.0_192", you need check if there are 2 versions of java installed on your system!